# 1 hour 50 min layover at PEK (Beijing International Airport)

Tags: air-travel, transit, short-connections, pek

I am being offered a trip from YYZ (Toronto Pearson Airport) to MNL (Manila International Airport) via PEK (Beijing Airport) ON Air China with 1 Hour 50 Min layover at PEK.

Is this transit thru PEK doable?  Do we have to clear immigration and customs thru PEK?

Comment: Air China do not fly from Toronto Pearson to Beijing!

Comment: As Doc notes, Air China does not operate YYZ-PEK; they codeshare the Air Canada flight.

Answer (score 3):

Air China do not fly from Toronto Pearson to Beijing, so you must be on a different airline for at least that leg of the flight.

Presuming that airline is Air Canada, or at least some other carrier that uses terminal 3, then 1 hour 50 minutes is tight, but probably doable.  The minimum connection time is 60 minutes, so you're above that means that the airline will (likely) re-route you if there is a problem - presuming both flights were booked on the same ticket.

You WILL need to go through some form of an immigration check.  It's different to the immigration counter you'd go through to enter the country, and depending on the time of day the line at this area can be long - 30 minute or more delays are not uncommon.

Once you get through the immigration check there is a further security check, and then eventually you'll be let into the departure area to catch your connecting flight.

If you're using another airline that does not use terminal 3, then 110 minutes is NOT sufficient - even the minimum connection time is at least 2 hours depending on which terminals are involved.

Comment: "You WILL need to go through some form of an immigration check" Not at PEK (unlike at other airports)

Answer (score 2):

It is doable, though quite tight. They usually give you priority through the airport lines if they know that your connecting flight is taking off soon. You do not to clear immigration nor customs through PEK if you're final destination is Manila.

Comment: do not to clear -> do not need to clear?