# How long to clear international arrival Beijing T3 and Transfer to T2 Domestic?

Tags: transit, short-connections, pek

I am arriving at 4:10 PM, T3 Beijing from International flight and will transfer to a domestic flight leaving at 6 PM from T2.  About how long will it take to clear customs in T3 and get to Terminal 2 (T2)?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81989/32134 Q1: Is this on one ticket? Q2 do you have checked-in luggage?

Comment: The related answer also suggests that 1:50 is not enough to make the connection. However if it is sold to you as one ticket and you would not mind catching a later connecting flight courtesy of the airline it could still be fine.

Comment: @mts Assuming there is a later flight, with available seats, of course. Even on one ticket, it is worth questioning this kind of connection.

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely have to pick up your baggage and check them into your connecting flight. Clearing customs depends on the time of day and the amount of people on your flight. Usually, it takes about an hour to clear customs.

Comment: There's no "mostly likely" about it. This is an international to domestic connection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.  I moved the flight to a later time and this proved to be a good thing. After picking up baggage and customs I had to take a bus to T2. I would have never made the connecting domestic flight in time. Domestic flights on China Southern require a bus ride to the plane, so boarding starts early.  Since it was two different airlines I had to pick up my baggage, go through security and recheck in at the second terminal. Based on my experience I would recommend at least three hours to make a transfer from International to Domestic at PEK.